# Mapbox Telemetry issue Android 11

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl, android-11, mapbox-android

These are the mapbox dependencies I have used in *build.gradle* file

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-places-v9:0.12.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:6.1.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v9:0.9.0'
```

Mapbox view is crashing in Android 11. I found this solution https://github.com/nativescript-community/ui-mapbox/issues/19#issuecomment-771161902 which seems to be resolving the issue in Android 11, but when I ran the app for Android 10, it crashed (which didn't used to happen before).

What solution should I use for Mapbox Telemetry to work in Android 11 ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using

> implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:6.1.0'

You need to update version.

Comment: It is better to point to a specific version which will resolve this issue.

Also, the OP has a fix in place for Android 11 but changing the dependency version will break their build for Android 10. It will be helpful if the OP can be pointed to resources to work around this complication.

Comment: @NSaran The latest available version is [v8.1.3](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-android/releases). It's not only through Mapbox Downloads API and it could be a potential issue for open source projects: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-android/issues/563